# Issue comparing 2 dates using parsley javascript

Tags: javascript, date, parsley.js

Am working on a form whereby I have 2 inputs containing 2 date inputs mainly the departure date and return date. I am using parsley javascript for validation. I need assistance in creating a custom Js validation rule that compares the 2 fields and checks **departure date is a date after today** while **return date should be 3 days or more after departure date**

**Inputs on the form**

```
 <!-- Departure date-->
        <div class="form-line registar2 love {{ $errors->has('departure_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                 <input type="date" class="form-input" name="departure_date" value="{{ old('departure_date') }}" required data-parsley-depart= ''>

                 <label>Departure Date *</label>
                <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
                <div class="check-label"></div>
                  @if ($errors->has('departure_date'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('departure_date') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                  @endif
        </div>
    <!--End departure-->

    <!-- Return date-->
        <div class="form-line registar2 move {{ $errors->has('return_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                 <input type="date" class="form-input" name="return_date" value="{{ old('return_date') }}" required data-parsley-return= ''>

                 <label>Return Date *</label>
                <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
                <div class="check-label"></div>
                  @if ($errors->has('return_date'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('return_date') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                  @endif
        </div>
    <!-- End return date-->
```

**Custom Parsley Js code**

```
//Deparure date
window.Parsley.addValidator('departure_date', {
  validateString: function (value) {
            var now = new Date();
            var date = new Date(value);
            return date < now;
        }
  messages: {
    en: 'Please insert tomorrow or anydate in the future'
  }
});

//Return date
window.Parsley.addValidator('return_date', {
  validateString: function (value) {
            var now = new Date();
            var date = new Date(value);
            return date < now;
  },
  messages: {
    en: 'Your return date should be 3 days or more after departure date'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with dependencies is a bit tricky. You can either do something like [in this example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html), or add a validator to one input and trigger an `'input'` event there when the other input receives an `'input'` event.